# how to pass a string to an already opened activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onresume

I have 3 Activities A1,A2,A3

A1 call A2  (A1 goes to stack)

A2 call A3  (A2 also goes to stack)

And A3 call A1  (A1 should call from stack not new instance...)

I don't want to Create new instance of A1 just i want to call it from stack

I want to send some Extra String to A1, the problem is here, when i send some String by using putExtra() to A1, A1 can not seen it!

I put getIntent() in onResume() for A1 but it s not working...

Code in A3

```
Intent in = new Intent(A3.this,A1.class);
in.putExtra("ACTIVITY", "A3");
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(in);
```

Code in A1

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Log.e("LOG", getIntent().getExtras().getString("ACTIVITY"));
  if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ACTIVITY")=="A3"){
     new LoadAllMyOrders().execute();
  }else{
     new LoadAllMyshops().execute();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an Application Level Static Variable and set its value from wherever  you want ,
then you can access it from your activity !!

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood, you can accomplish this behaviour with the pair `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`. Also, string comparison in Java is perfomerd through the `equals` method. `==` compares String references

Answer (score 1):

You should compare strings with equals(), e.g.

`if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ACTIVITY").equals("A3")`

With `==` you're just comparing object references, which also might be the reason that this expression evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Launch Mode of A1 to "singleTask", and you should get the intent from the method " void onNewIntent(...)" of the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences for that variable or you can make a gettersetter class and use its object to access it anywhere.